# Is there a way to navigate from a generated html link in angular?

Tags: angular

I am using a third party component to display notifications (PrimeNg if you want to know). The message parameter in the notification component is a simple string. But it accept html.
What I am trying to do is to display a link in my error message. A link to another page of my app. The problem is that when I'm doing this with a normal  tag, when the user click on it, it reload the entire application!
I want the user to be able to navigate using the router the same way it will do if he use my menu.

Is there any way to achieve that?

The html code:

```
...
<p-growl [value]="msgs" [life]="lifeTime" [sticky]="stycky" [style]="{'width':'auto', 'display': 'inline-block', 'text-align': 'center'}" (onClose)="onClosingMessage()"></p-growl>
...
```

The typescript code

```
...
constructor(@Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) private baseHref: string) {}
...
this.msgs.push({severity:'error', summary:'Error Message', detail:`<div>An error has occurred, please go to the <a href="${this.baseHref}execution">execution page</a> to see the details.</div>`});
...
```

Comment: Consider sharing the code you are having trouble with, please.

Comment: Can you paste the html of the link that is generated in the notification by the PrimeNg bundle?

Comment: I have added some code sample. Any idea someone?